# How to form a Third java Array from given Two String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, array-initialization

I am writing a java code for processing of signals where I have come accross a situation as explained below:

INPUT GIVEN: String Arrays arr1 and arr2.
OUTPUT REQD: String Array arr3

```
      String[] arr1= {"A", "c", "c",  "", "", "c", "c", "B", "", "c","c", "", "A",  "", "", "B", "B", "A"};
      String[] arr2= {"2", "3", "3",  "", "", "2", "1", "3", "", "2","3", "", "2",  "", "", "3", "2", "3"};
      String[] arr3= {"11", "",  "",  "", "", "",  "",  "8", "", "",  "", "", "2",  "", "", "3", "2", "3"};
```

ALGORITHM: 
  1. arr1 has elements of 4 types: "A", "B" and "c" and "".

2. arr2 has some Number Strings like "2", "3" etc. at corresponding index to "A", "B" and "c" in arr1, element "" in arr1 has corresponding element "" in arr2.
3. arr3 is to be formed from arr1 and arr2.
4. arr3 has Number Strings only corresponding to "A", "B" elemnts in arr1.
5. In arr3 the first Number String "11" is from the total of "2", "3", "3",  "", "", "2", "1". These are the elements from "A" to "B"(including "A", excluding "B"). "8" is from the total of "3", "", "2","3", "". Next "2" is from the total of "2",  "", "". At last it is clear that "3", "2", "3" are from "3", "2", "3" respectively.

   Being new comer to programming and java I need help in the above case. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What's your actual _specific question_?  As it stands, your question reads like a rather broad homework request.

Comment: If this is an assignment, then your first source for help should be your professor/teacher, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi, this is not assignment, it is a very concrete need. Even  a pseudocode can help me.

Comment: @Garry, you can write pseudocode. In comments, describe the steps in a human language, as you would to someone who needs precise instructions . Then take one of those steps and write code for it. Repeat. You can start with "for each index in arr1, in ascending order". Then come to stackoverflow if you have specific questions about something you've tried. Don't expect stackoverflow users to write your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to declare arr2 and arr3 as int arrays, that will help you do any mathematical operations easily.

And speaking about the approach for the solution, what we can do is maintain an index common for all 3 arrays and then perform the checks on arr1 and necessary operations on arr2 and arr3.

```
String[] arr1 = {"A", "c", "c",  "", "", "c", "c", "B", "", "c","c", "", "A",  "", "", "B", "B", "A"};
int[] arr2 = {2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3};

int len = arr1.length, sum=0;
int[] arr3 = new int[len];

for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
    arr3[i] = 0;
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ ){
    sum=0;
    if(arr1[i].equals("A") || arr1[i].equals("B")){
        sum += arr2[i];
        int j=0;
        for(j = i+1; j < len && !arr1[j].equals("A") && !arr1[j].equals("B"); j++){
            sum += arr2[j];
        }
        arr3[i] = sum;
        i= j-1 ;
    }
}
```

The above piece of code now fills the arr3 with necessary values you can change them to strings by using the `Integer.toString()` method on each of the value.

If you need any further clarifications let me know. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Hi VamshiAlladi, WONDERFUL !!! You have given me exactly what I wanted. Your code is crystal clear and it has worked, and has solved my whole problem with great ease. I consider you a mastermind.

Comment: Haha that was really a great appreciation. Thank you @Garry, feeling inspired.